# Using multiple DbContexts with their own transaction scopes

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-4, transactions

I need to access data from two different DbContexts at the same time, making sure each uses READ UNCOMMITTED for their queries (*really, the important thing is that it doesn't lock the rows it iterates over - adding WITH NO LOCK to the query would work too*).

How can you do this using Entity Framework? If I wrap each of the two queries in a TransactionScope, it tries to promote the transaction to MSDTC which isn't an option for us.

```css
private static IEnumerable<Image> EnumerateSourceImages()
{
    using (var dbContext = new SourceDbContext())
    {
        using (var transScope = new TransactionScope(
                                    TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew,
                                    new TransactionOptions() {
                                            IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted
                                        }
                                    )
                            )
        {
            var imagesSourceQuery = dbContext.ImageDatas
                                    .AsNoTracking()
                                    .OrderBy(imageData => imageData.ImageID)
            foreach (var image in imagesSourceQuery)
            {
                yield return image;
            }
            transScope.Complete();
        }
    }
}
private static IEnumerable<Image> EnumerateDestinationImages()
{
    using (var dbContext = new DestinationDbContext())
    {
        using (var transScope = new TransactionScope(
                                    TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew,
                                    new TransactionOptions() {
                                            IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted
                                        }
                                    )
                            )
        {
            var imagesSourceQuery = dbContext.ImageDatas
                                .AsNoTracking()
                                .OrderBy(imageData => imageData.ImageID)
            foreach (var image in imagesSourceQuery)
            {
                yield return image;
            }
            transScope.Complete();
        }
    }
}
private static void main(string[] args){
{
    IEnumerator<ItemImage> sourceImagesEnumerator = null;
    IEnumerator<ItemImage> destImagesEnumerator = null;
    try{
        sourceImagesEnumerator = EnumerateSourceImages().GetEnumerator();
        destImagesEnumerator = EnumerateDestinationImages().GetEnumerator();

        bool sourceHasMore = sourceImagesEnumerator.MoveNext();
        //Exception on next line about MSDTC Promotion
        bool destHasMore = destImagesEnumerator.MoveNext();
    } finally{
        if(sourceImagesEnumerator != null) sourceImagesEnumerator.Dispose();
        if(destImagesEnumerator != null) destImagesEnumerator.Dispose():
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to add a tag for the database you want this to work with, since the answer will be very different depending on that.

Comment: What exception are you receiving?

Comment: Why not to iterate / materialize each query separately?

Comment: @ladislav-mrnka Because it would take excessive amounts of memory - probably more than the machine has available.

Comment: @xharze `System.Transactions.TransactionManagerCommunicationException` - which happens, if I'm understanding things correctly, because it realizes the transaction is spanning multiple connections (and to different servers), and it's trying to promote it to a MSDTC managed transaction.  I don't really want both actions to be performed in the same transaction - I just want it to do both queries using READ UNCOMMITTED isolation levels, or possibly to add WITH NO LOCK to the queries it builds.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting enlist=false in your connection string?

http://forums.asp.net/t/1401606.aspx/1

Brgrds, 
Lari

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.   Looking at the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx  it seems that this would stop it from honoring the transaction-scopes entirely. This wouldn't help with the goal though.